# WHM / cPanel: mySQL back-up

Tags: mysql, backup

I am setting a new server, with WHM / cPanel installed.

It is very important that I can take a full mySQL back-up once or twice a day.

Right now the databases are pretty small (20 mb), but volume will increase rapidly as soon s we get more customers.

I now there is a possibility to create a cron job and have the back-up emailed.
However, I think it is a shitty solution due to the future size of these back-up's.

What are your best advices regarding daily mySQL back-ups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a cron job set up to back up your database and dump it to a directory of your choosing:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --skip-lock-tables | gzip -9 > /your/backup/dir/here/`date +%Y%m%d`_backup.sql.gz
```

What you do from there is up to you, but I agree that you should not email it due to the size.  Perhaps you can use [SCP](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) to send it to a different server.

Comment: Why `skip-lock-tables`? In the vast majority of user applications, the default `--opt` settings would be suitable.  You would most likely want `--lock-tables` on to get a consistent data snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice for backups is as follows

1. Do a daily backup.
2. Once the first daily reaches a week old, start deleting things, but keep the one that hit a week old.
3. Start keeping monthly backups, deleting all weekly once the first one hits a month old.

You can continue to do this with yearly as well.

The whole point of this is that you *should* catch any errors in information *before* your backups hit the week mark. You shouldn't really need to keep the *REALLY* old backups for any specific purpose, so that is why you start deleting things.

Unless you have unlimited space on various disks, you would probably be best to follow this practice, and just make sure nothing happens to your data.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that your data will grow to considerable size to where it will cause significant database downtime to make dumps, you first ought to look into implementing a replicated set up to where you can take the dumps off the slave.

You can certainly run a simple `mysqldump` command from within cron, placing dumps into a drive on the machine.  You can then worry about moving the data off the machine by some other means (you don't want to email it). Just keep in mind that it will lock your database up briefly for as long as your data dump takes to complete.

If you want to think out of the box, you could just implement a MySQL instance on Amazon RDS.  It can do the replication, database snapshots, etc. with basically push-button ease.